# Error in keystore password generating in command prompt

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, google-play-services

[keystore key generating error ]when i generating the application signature in command prompt it shows warning how to rectify this

Comment: Did you get the key properly?

Comment: no i didnt get key it shows error pls check that link in question

Comment: sorry i cant understand

Comment: What did you mean by this? `When i enter in to the Google play store it shows server error `

Comment: Sorry i am entering wrong keywords.now see the question sir

Comment: What is your actual aim? To create certificate for your app? Or hashkey?